# jquery: make date picker show/hide via image?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use an image of a calendar to show/hide the jquery datepicker. Based on the documentation it looks like I need to set buttonImage and buttonImageOnly, which I have. the date picker is working but it is always visible. here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    altField: '#from', 
    altFormat: 'yymmdd', 
    buttonImage: 'datepicker.png', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    defaultDate: <?=getDaysFromToday($_GET['from'])?>, 
    showOn: 'focus' 
    });
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("#myform").submit(); 
    }
});
 </script>
```

Also I am trying to make it submit a form when you choose a date, I can't seem to get that to work either.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
showOn: 'focus'
```

with

```
showOn: 'button'
```

This will make the datepicker appear only when the button is clicked, not when the text field gets the focus.

Can't tell you why the form submit doesn't work. Have you bound any submit events to the form that might be returning false?

Since `this` refres to the input element inside the event handler, perhaps you can try this for the submit:

```
this.form.submit();
```

**Edit after comment**: Have a look at [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/icon-trigger.html), the button gets added automatically.

I've just realized you have two separate calls to `datepicker`. Combining the two into one might help with your event problems:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    altField: '#from', 
    altFormat: 'yymmdd', 
    buttonImage: 'datepicker.png', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    defaultDate: <?=getDaysFromToday($_GET['from'])?>, 
    showOn: 'focus'.
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#myform").submit(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, no luck. Am I supposed to manually add a button? or is it supposed to add the button for me? The documentation doesn't really say.

Comment: After looking at your example I noticed that #datepicker was the input text in question I had it as a seperate div. After changing that, the datepicker is initially hidden and the button is now there. However, clicking the button seems not to do anything. I think somehow none of the jquery events are triggering because I can't get any other events to trigger either. Maybe that should be a new question though.

Comment: Your last edit fixed everything!! I needed to combine the 2 calls. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking to position the icon not too close beside the input field:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/altering-position-of-datepicker-icon#14737000001522067

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
margin-left : 5px;
vertical-align : top;
}
```